# How to Create Sharepoint 2013 Workflows using Visual studio?

Tags: 2013

Well,

I am working on one model which needs to implement share-point 2013 workflow, which should be custom workflow using visual studio 2013!
I am beginner for this. Can anybody tell me the road map?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft SharePoint 2013 provides two primary workflow development environments for authoring workflows: Microsoft SharePoint Designer and Microsoft Visual Studio. However, what differs from previous versions is that using Visual Studio no longer provides a code-based authoring strategy. Instead, both SharePoint Designer and Visual Studio provide a fully declarative, no-code authoring environment regardless of the development tool you select.

So to start with you can check following which describer end to end workflows development.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163199(v=office.15).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163917(v=office.15).aspx

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SBsQSpJrYR4